# getting an "AAPT: error: :string>." when trying to run a project I download from github

Tags: xml, android-studio, kotlin, github

For my final project with my friends we have to make an App so my friend made the screens and now I have to work with them. The problem is when I try to run what I have download from github I´m getting this error message:
[image]

I dont what I have done wrong to being unable to run It. I havent change anything from it.

here is my xml file:

```
<resources>


<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <string name="app_name">BancoV1</string>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/black</item>
</style>
<!-- TODO: Remove or change this placeholder text -->
<string name="hello_blank_fragment">Hello blank fragment</string>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your custom style method is wrong. You need to move the definition related to `<string name="app_name"></string>` in the code to the outside. In addition, the `name` of string also needs to be modified. `Android` has defined the string of `app_name` by default

```kotlin
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/black</item>
</style>
<!-- TODO: Remove or change this placeholder text -->
<string name="app_name2">BancoV1</string>
<string name="hello_blank_fragment">Hello blank fragment</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

As there is an error in the `string.xml` file please go and see what was that and try to resolve it and give it a try.

Can you please post your `string.xml` as well here for a better understanding?

Also by seeing the exception is caused due to the duplicate values as mentioned at the bottom of the exception in screenshot.

Comment: There is no display exception that duplication of resources